Is this leaf spot disease?
I have this tall dracaena marginata tree in my home. It has 2 heads. I noticed the one head has a bunch of spots on its leaves. The other head doesn't have these spots. I'm thinking it's leaf spot disease but not sure. What is the proper treatment for it if it is leaf spot disease? I know I need to spray it with fungicide but for how long do I do this for? Do I need to remove any leaf that has a spot?




Yes, this is a fungus/virus/bacteria which has taken advantage of too much water in the root ball to get going.  Diagnostic clues are:

appears on older growth first
starts as a spot then gets larger with characteristic dark rings
overwatering or peat based potting soil that is old and has compacted

Fungicide will not control this unless you change the underlying conditions.  Most plants can outgrow this if they get the following:

more light
less water

I also see what could be a nutrient deficiency or just low light where the veins are dark green and the rest of the leaf is a lighter green.  If this plant has not had fresh potting soil or been repotted in the past few years consider removing the plant from the pot and adding an inch or two of fresh tropical plant potting mix in the bottom of the pot.  Then put the root ball back in and job done!
Also, these plants are notorious for getting spider mites.  Look on the underside of the leaves for what looks like tiny grains of salt.  Webbing is another sign.  If they are found control with a little bit of dish soap and lots of water. Wipe the leaves top and bottom and then rinse. Repeat at least twice at five to seven day intervals.
